# Redirecting user after login depending on their level of access (usergroup)

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, authentication

this is my first post so excuse the novice like remarks. I'm okay with PHP but I seem to be missing something here (obviously). I'm looking to redirect users after they have logged in depending on the usergroup they are assigned. So members will go to the member's area, admin to admin area, and finally superadmin to the superadmin area. The code was recently working but seems to have stopped after I added a Javascript dropdown menu for links at the top of the webpage. I have narrowed the problem down to this snippet:

```
    if($count==1){

        // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
        $_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
        $_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword;
        $_SESSION['myusergroup'] = $myusergroup;
            if($usergroup == "SuperAdmin"){
            header("location:superadmin_login_success.php");
            exit();
            }
            elseif($usergroup == "Admin"){
            header("location:admin_login_success.php");
            exit();
            }
            elseif($usergroup == "Member"){
            header("location:login_success.php");
            exit();
            }
    }
```

The count represents the results returned from the SQL query. The query selects all fields from a table where the username and passwords fields equal to the form i have submitted previously on login. All of my login PHP code is located on the same webpage and an if statement at the beginning of the PHP prevent the code from being executed when the form hasnt been submitted. Can anyone spot anything wrong with this snippet or my logic, I've been staring and reading around the issue from people in similar situations and I still cant get anywhere.

As you can see I'm using the header function to redirect, and there is issues with the functions when print output onto the page before the header is called. I'm not entirely sure on the specifics of the issue but if anyone can clarify and give and example, then I will be grateful. Is it appropriate and correct to write these scripts seperately and then include them when required? I've also been thinking about that.

Many Thanks

Rhys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the difference between $myusergroup and $usergroup?  Your if statements check on $usergroup.   Is that set or should it be $myusergroup that they check on?

Comment: Thank you, I recently changed the

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have no output before sending `header()`. Even little white space can ruin your redirect.

Comment: Thank you. I now understand the way the header has to be placed above any printed HTML or PHP!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ob_start()` to turn on output buffering. Take a look at PHP's [Output Control Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php).

***Tip:** use `switch()` instead of several `if()` statements*

Answer (score 0):

i noticed that you are assigning $myusergroup to your session variable but in your if statements you are only calling $usergroup.  is $usergroup used somewhere else?

Comment: Thank you, I recently changed the variable to partner the similar naming convention used with the username and password. I now also understand the way the header has to be placed above any printed HTML or PHP. Thank you again.